# How do I create a table in which one column has a variable number of equal-width sub-columns?

Tags: tables

I am currently writing a lab write-up, and am trying to make a table that looks something like this:

```
|Number of lightbulbs|Voltage from battery|Voltage in lightbulbs|
|         1          |         2.6 V      |        2.2 V        |
|         2          |         2.8 V      |  1.9 V  |   0.5 V   |
|         3          |         1.2 V      | 1.2 V |0.2 V |0.6 V |
```

I tried writing it like this:

```
\begin {tabular} {|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Number of Lightbulbs & Voltage from Battery & \multicolumn {6}{|c|}{Voltage in Lightbulbs} \\
    \hline
    1 & 2.6 & \multicolumn {6}{|c|}{2.2 V} \\
    \hline
    2 & 2.8 V & \multicolumn {3}{|c|}{2.5 V} & \multicolumn {3}{|c|}{0.5 V} \\
    \hline
    3 & 2.8 V & \multicolumn {2}{|c|}{1.2 V} & \multicolumn {2}{|c|}{0.2 V} & \multicolumn {2}{|c|}{0.6 V} \\
    \hline
\end {tabular}
```

However, this ends up putting the second row divided 1/3 and 2/3, rather than 1/2 and 1/2.  How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With nested tables this would be simple :-):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcommand{\xmc}[2]{\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}[t]{@{}
                      *{#1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}@{}}
                        #2
                     \end{tabularx}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular} {|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{45mm}@{}}
    \hline
Number of Lightbulbs & Voltage from Battery 
                &   \xmc{1}{Voltage in Lightbulbs}  \\
    \hline
1   &   2.6 V   &   \xmc{1}{2.2 V}                  \\
    \hline
2   &   2.8 V   &   \xmc{2}{2.5 V & 0.5 V}          \\
    \hline
3   &   2.8 V   &   \xmc{3}{1.2 V & 0.2 V & 0.6 V}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** use of new command `xcm` in the first two rows is necessary for the most right vertical line in the table. If it is determined in the main table, then is repeated in the last two rows. Since this is visible, I decided for presented solution.

Now I also add option `[t]` to  `tabularx`. By it is preserve connection of all lines in table if you will use `\arraystretch` different from 1 or use `\extrarowheight` (thanks to Mico who pointed me on this important detail).

Comment: @Mico, I didn't consider the use `\arraystretch` or `\extrarowheight` :-( , now I also correct this my cursory.

Comment: Thanks. I've deleted my earlier comments. You may want to insert a comment in the code explaining what the `[t]` particle is about.